# I don't understand why in both cases future continuous is used

Tags: future-continuous

He hasn't told his boss that he **won't be coming** back after his vacation

John **won't be driving** to work any more after his arrest for being drunk at the wheel.

why not won't come and won't drive, it is something that is definitive not temporary or is the progressive here to show that it is  temporary, that in the first case he will return one day to work and the second case his suspension has a limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that we use future progressive is explained in [this article](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-future-tense/):

> The simple future is used ... **In the negative form, to express unwillingness**:
>   The baby won't eat his soup.
>   I won't leave until I've seen the manager!

If something isn't going to happen due to external factors rather than due to unwillingless, we use the future progressive even if the verb clearly relates to a single action.

Comment: thanks for your clear explination, now I have understood